# GTK Timer - How to make a timer within a frame

Tags: c, timer, gtk

How do g_timer_new works?

is it possible to do a

```
char timerz[50];

GTimer *timer


g_timer_start(GTimer *timer);

strcpy(timerz,(g_timer_elapsed(GTimer *timer))
```

Or what Could I do to have a timer in a gtk_frame???

Have a nice day! :D

Comment: Err that is some scary code you have there. `g_timer_elapsed` returns a gdouble & using it in strcpy is not a good idea! Timer in a gtk_frame makes no sense :) ... what is the requirement? Do you want any element to be updated at regular interval?

Comment: @another.anon.coward I want a frame with a timer inside, The only thing I've found so far in timer is GTimer, do you know another way I could accomplish this with a less scarier code? Hehehe

Comment: Sure there is :)... Do you want to display time? or time elapsed?

Comment: @another.anon.coward I want it so the label inside the frame(box) counts in real-time. of the time elapsed of the turn of the player.(The program is a game..)

Comment: You can have a timer callback added which can triggered every x millisecond. Although its not a hard timer, it can delayed at times. I had an example, I will lookup & post it

Comment: Do you have a requirement of pausing & resuming the timer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `g_timeout_add` or `g_timeout_add_seconds` which will call a timeout function at regular interval. Please note that this timeout function can be delayed due to event processing and should not be relied on for precise timing. Check [this developer page](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html) for more info on main loop.
Here is an example to get you started (you can improvise over this). In the example the timeout is set in seconds thus using `g_timeout_add_seconds`, use `g_timeout_add` if you need millisecond precision.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

/* Determines if to continue the timer or not */
static gboolean continue_timer = FALSE;

/* Determines if the timer has started */
static gboolean start_timer = FALSE;

/* Display seconds expired */
static int sec_expired = 0;

static void
_quit_cb (GtkWidget *button, gpointer data)
{
    (void)button; (void)data; /*Avoid compiler warnings*/
    gtk_main_quit();
    return;
}


static gboolean
_label_update(gpointer data)
{
    GtkLabel *label = (GtkLabel*)data;
    char buf[256];
    memset(&buf, 0x0, 256);
    snprintf(buf, 255, "Time elapsed: %d secs", ++sec_expired);
    gtk_label_set_label(label, buf);
    return continue_timer;

}

static void
_start_timer (GtkWidget *button, gpointer data)
{
    (void)button;/*Avoid compiler warnings*/
    GtkWidget *label = data;
    if(!start_timer)
    {
        g_timeout_add_seconds(1, _label_update, label);
        start_timer = TRUE;
        continue_timer = TRUE;
    }
}

static void
_pause_resume_timer (GtkWidget *button, gpointer data)
{
    (void)button;/*Avoid compiler warnings*/
    if(start_timer)
    {
        GtkWidget *label = data;
        continue_timer = !continue_timer;
        if(continue_timer)
        {
            g_timeout_add_seconds(1, _label_update, label);
        }
        else
        {
            /*Decrementing because timer will be hit one more time before expiring*/
            sec_expired--;
        }
    }
}

static void
_reset_timer (GtkWidget *button, gpointer data)
{
    (void)button; (void)data;/*Avoid compiler warnings*/
    /*Setting to -1 instead of 0, because timer will be triggered once more before expiring*/
    sec_expired = -1;
    continue_timer = FALSE;
    start_timer = FALSE;
}

int main(void)
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *vbox;
    GtkWidget *start_button;
    GtkWidget *pause_resume_button;
    GtkWidget *reset_button;
    GtkWidget *quit_button;
    GtkWidget *label;

    gtk_init(NULL, NULL);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy", 
                    G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit),
                    NULL);
    vbox = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 2);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

    label = gtk_label_new("Time elapsed: 0 secs");

    start_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Start");
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(start_button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(_start_timer), label);

    pause_resume_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Pause/Resume");
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(pause_resume_button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(_pause_resume_timer), label);

    reset_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Reset");
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(reset_button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(_reset_timer), label);

    quit_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Quit");
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(quit_button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(_quit_cb), NULL);

    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX(vbox), label, 0, 0, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX(vbox), start_button, 0, 0, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX(vbox), pause_resume_button, 0, 0, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX(vbox), reset_button, 0, 0, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), quit_button, 0, 0, 0);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    g_timeout_add_seconds(1, _label_update, label);
    continue_timer = TRUE;
    start_timer = TRUE;

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. vbox = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 2);
   In this line, "vbox" needs to be replaced with "box".
2. int main(int argc, char **argv);
3. gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).