# gtk_main() alongside while(1) Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, gtk, geany

I've just started my first project in C language on raspberry pi 3 and I want to create my first GUI app for touch panel.
My goal is to run the while(1) loop which controls the raspberry I/O and the gtk_main function to open a simple window.

After calling gtk_main(), the rest of the code doesn't work. I know it's caused by the fact that gtk_main creates it's own loop. Is there any way to run these two loops simultaneously?

```
#include <stdio.h>    // Used for printf() statements
#include <wiringPi.h> // Include WiringPi library!
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

// Pin number declarations. We're using the Broadcom chip pin numbers.
const int pwmPin = 18; // PWM LED - Broadcom pin 18, P1 pin 12
const int ledPin = 23; // Regular LED - Broadcom pin 23, P1 pin 16
const int butPin = 21; // Active-low button - Broadcom pin 17, P1 pin 11    

const int pwmValue = 0; // Use this to set an LED brightness

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int add = 0;
    int sign = 1;
    // Setup stuff:
    wiringPiSetupGpio(); // Initialize wiringPi -- using Broadcom pin numbers

    pinMode(pwmPin, PWM_OUTPUT); // Set PWM LED as PWM output
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);     // Set regular LED as output
    pinMode(butPin, INPUT);      // Set button as INPUT
    pullUpDnControl(butPin, PUD_UP); // Enable pull-up resistor on button

    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_show (window);

    gtk_main ();

    // Loop (while(1)):
    while(1)
    {
        if (digitalRead(butPin)) // Button is released if this returns 1
        {
            pwmWrite(pwmPin, pwmValue+add); // PWM LED at bright setting
            digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);     // Regular LED off
            add=add+(sign*50);
            if (add==1000) sign=-1;
            if (add==0) sign=1;
            delay(50);
        }
        else // If digitalRead returns 0, button is pressed
        {
            pwmWrite(pwmPin, 1024 - pwmValue); // PWM LED at dim setting
            // Do some blinking on the ledPin:
            digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); // Turn LED ON
            delay(75); // Wait 75ms
            digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); // Turn LED OFF
            delay(75); // Wait 75ms again
        }
    }    

}
```

Comment: Not an GTK expert but you should consider to use multitasking to do so.

Answer (score 1):

`gtk_main` is [documented](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html#gtk-main) as:

> Runs the main loop until `gtk_main_quit()` is called.
>
> You can nest calls to `gtk_main()`. In that case `gtk_main_quit()` will make the innermost invocation of the main loop return.

So you need to have some [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) *explicitly* invoking `gtk_main_quit`  (and I guess you don't).

So the behavior is expected. You may want to handle the [`"delete-event"` GTK signal](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-delete-event) on your `window` (by having *your* GTK signal handler for that event calling *explicitly* `gtk_main_quit`). You need to read much more, notably about the [GTK event loop](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html), and [GObject's signals](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-Signals.html).

If you want to [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) and [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) some device, you'll better do that *inside* the GTK event loop (e.g. by calling [g_source_add_unix_fd](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-add-unix-fd) or [g_io_channel_unix_new](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-IO-Channels.html#g-io-channel-unix-new), etc etc...).

<sup>You should spend several days reading more about Gtk, notably its [Getting Started](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html) chapter.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I have two solution in mind to solve your problem:

- You could [create a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8353435/1212012) which will call a function to deal with `butPin` value each 100ms,
- You could use threads:

  ```
  void *start_gtk_thread(void *arg)
  {
      gtk_main();
      return NULL;
  }
  void *start_pin_thread(void *arg)
  {
      while(1)
      {
          if (digitalRead(butPin)) // Button is released if this returns 1
          {
               ....
          }
          return NULL;
      }
  }
  ```

  **And in your main function**

  ```
  gtk_widget_show (window);

  /* threads id*/
  pthread_t tid[2];

  /* create threads */        
  pthread_create(&tid[0], NULL, start_gtk_thread, NULL);
  pthread_create(&tid[1], NULL, start_pin_thread, NULL);

  /* wait for threads (warning, they should never terminate) */ 
  pthread_join(id[0], NULL);
  pthread_join(id[1], NULL);
  ```

Comment: I don't recommend using threads in a Gtk application coded by a newbie; using threads with GTK is quite advanced topic, notably because most GTK functions can only be called from the *main* thread.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your while loop and use `g_idle_add` and/or `g_timeout` to trigger your callbacks. This defines **when** your code is called. Then in your callback, do your pin I/O control stuff. Just remember that using `delay` or any blocking function similar to `sleep` will freeze your UI for the same amount of time. You may avoid this by using `g_idle_add` or `g_timeout` to trigger for changing the state again.